# Vuechart js not rendering on a component

Tags: chart.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to use the [vue-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs) npm package, but my code below is not rendering the chart. I'm using VueJS 2 and have already installed the package using `npm`.

```
<canvas id="chartRecord" width="100%" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
  import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
  export default {
    mounted () {
      Line.renderChart({
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'GitHub Commits',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
        }]
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

I'm getting this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue_chartjs__.Line.renderChart` is not a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vue-chartjs` module provides Vue components that are intended to be extended in order to customize.

The correct syntax to do what you're trying to do:

```
// MyChart.js
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
export default Line.extend({
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'GitHub Commits',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

Notice that you can simply put this in a `.js` file as there's no need to specify a template since it's already included in the `Line` component being imported, and since styling is mostly done in the options of the chart.

You can then import the extended component like any other component:

```
//Parent.vue
<template>
  <my-chart></my-chart>
</template>

<script>
import MyChart from './MyChart'

export default {
  components: { MyChart }
}
</script>
```

[See the documentation.](http://vue-chartjs.org/#/home)

Comment: Can you please explain a lil bit? and where should I put that script? and how to access it inside my component. Thank!

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Tried it and added `Chartrecord.js` inside js folder. my components are inside components folder but no luck.

Comment: What do you mean "no luck"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes it says `Cannot find module `Unexpected token, expected , (17:0)`

Comment: That means there's something wrong with one of your `import` statements

Comment: Hey! Thanks, it's working now. Just added it inside a new vue file.

Comment: ue_chartjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Line.extend is not a function